# Get distinct rows along with sum of field

Tags: mysql, group-by

My table structure is like this shown in below URL:

http://tinypic.com/r/sm3xbb/8

I want to write a MySQL query to get sum of count field of all such rows which have same hash value but have distinct date value.

This can be done with Group by statement but I won't get all rows if I will perform group by on hash field.

Example: Rows with ID 1,4 and 8 have same hash value in table, so I want to retrieve all 3 rows along with SUM of count field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it with a subquery

```
SELECT t.*, 
(
  SELECT SUM(count)
    FROM table1
   WHERE hash = t.hash
) total
  FROM table1 t
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96c488/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
select t.*,t1.sum_count 
from mytable t 
join
(
select hash, sum(`count`) as sum_count
from mytable group by hash 
) t1 on t.hash = t1.hash
```

Comment: With your query sum_count seems to be zero

Comment: Nope, it can't be. Check your table data once.

Comment: Ya I checked , its not getting desired result

Comment: Strange. Can you post the table structure along with sample data as text for me to try and prove that it works.